# MACRO no Excel - impressão com números sequênciais

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, lógica, macro, microsoft-office

tenho uma macro de uns anos atrás que ainda funciona, quando clico em imprimir as ordens de produção da minha empresa, coloco o número de inicio e de fim, e a macro imprime as OPs com os números em ordem, segue a macro:

```
Sub PrintJobs()
Dim i As Long, startnum As Long, lastnum As Long

    startnum = Application.InputBox("Número de inicio", "Imprimir op", 1, , , , , 1)
    lastnum = Application.InputBox("Número de fim", "Imprimir op", 1, , , , , 1)

    For i = startnum To lastnum
        Range("G2").Value = i
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
    Next

End Sub
```

(G2 no código é a celula onde os números vão sair) o problema é que agora estou alterando as ops para sair duas por página (questão de econômia de folhas) metade da A4 sai com uma op, a outra metade sai outra op, fiz um espelho na planilha pra quando alterar a primeira op, altere também a segunda, fazendo as duas sair na mesma folha, só que agora a minha macro não funciona como deveria, pois quando a primeira op for 1, a segunda deveria ser 2 e assim por diante, já tentei colocar a segunda op como o valor da primeira + 1, sem sucesso, podem me ajudar para alterar minha macro, pra G2 sair 1, G32 sair 2, depois G2 sair 3, G32 sair 4, e assim por diante. Obrigado

Comment: Tente assim  `i = startnum`  `Do While i < lastnum`    `Range("G2").Value = i`    `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut`    `i = i + 1`    `Range("G32").Value = i`    `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut`    `i = i + 1`
`Loop`

Comment: Olá @MarcosRegis muito obrigado pela resposta, eu colei seu código e imprimi com exemplo de 1 á 4 , saiu assim: primeira folha, folha1: op1 saiu com numero 1, op 2 saiu com nº 4 ; folha2: saiu com op1 nº 1, op2 nº 2; folha3: op1 nº 3, op2 nº 2; folha4: op1 nº 3, op2 nº 4.
Tens alguma ideia de como arrumar isso?
agradeço desde já

Comment: E como deveria ser? Seria mais facil se postasse um print da planilha e o em que evento esta disparando

Comment: @MarcosRegis, agradeço imensamente sua ajuda, só tirei uma linha do seu código e funcionou perfeitamente!! muito obrigado mesmo! salvou o dia!
i = startnum
    Do While i < lastnum
    Range("G2").Value = i
    i = i + 1
    Range("G32").Value = i
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
    i = i + 1
    Loop

Comment: Vou colocar então como solução, me corrija se ficar errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela sua explicação acredito que ao invés de usar um laço **For** seja mais adequando usar um laço **While**

Tente com esse exemplo.

```
Sub PrintJobs()
    Dim i As Long, startnum As Long, lastnum As Long

    startnum = Application.InputBox("Número de inicio", "Imprimir op", 1, , , , , 1)
    lastnum = Application.InputBox("Número de fim", "Imprimir op", 1, , , , , 1)

    i = startnum
    Do While i < lastnum 
        Range("G2").Value = i 
        i = i + 1
        Range("G32").Value = i 
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
        i = i + 1 
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcos, funcionou perfeitamente!!